# Issues with a merged MP3 file

Tags: java, merge, mp3, duration

I have a Java application that allows a user to upload a user recorded MP3 file and then a copyright notice is merged on to the beginning of the file.  Without encoding and decoding the files this has been a bit of a chore (I avoided decoding/encoding because: 1. I really want to avoid the processing overhead 2. Not a big fan of the complexity of using dll's/shared libraries when running across different platforms i.e. LAME)

My solution is to read the sampling frequency, bit rate and mono/stereo characteristics of the uploaded file and choose a corresponding copyright introduction that matches those characteristics and then append that to the front of the file by reading in the introduction and the user recording as FileInputStream's and writing out the intro and the user file into a FileOutputStream.

The playback is where things get interesting.  Depending upon the OS/Browser and installed player,  in a web page will either display that the file has 35 seconds as a length (the intro length) OR will progressively increase the playing duration as the file is downloaded to the player (around 45 minutes in length).  I assume that the duration of the file is handled differently by different players and browsers.  Safari and Firefox on Win7 seems to take the "progressive" route where Chrome and IE9 on Win7 only display the 35 seconds of intro length although the ENTIRE 45 minute merged recording does play.

Finally, on iOS, Safari only displays NaN/NaN for duration and only plays for 15 minutes regardless of total length of the merged recording.

So, the conclusion I have come to is that the "merge" is still causing the issue.  The question is: Can I fix this without taking the more complex decode/encode route?  I remove the ID3 Tags of both files and then add tags back to the merged file using a jar from mp3agic.  All I can think of is that some players only read the frames of the introduction and then stop for some reason when the user portion of the recording is encountered.  I am not sure why this would happen except there must be some characteristic of the MP3 frame that I am missing that causes the player to think it has reached the end of the file (even though it continues to play past the first 35 seconds) as far as I know, there is no place the entire duration of an MP3 is stored.  It is the player that is left to calculate the playing duration of the file.

What should I be looking for?  I retain both the pre-merged and post-merged files and when I compare bit rates, sampling frequencies and mono/stereo characteristics, they are same. Merging supposedly identical files should work.  But there is something different in the frame (I assume) that buggers the player's duration calculation on some OS/Browser/Player combinations.  What am I missing?

Comment: Dont know much about this area but it's an interesting question - what do the various browser/OS combinations do on the original file? i.e. if you remove your append code and leave the MP3 as-is? Maybe those restrictions will still be present?